# Bad calculations after Python to C# port

Tags: c#, python, math, time, port

I'm working on a time-decay algorithm for a post system based on Reddit's model here:
http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588

My working port is here:

```
public class Calculation
{
    protected DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    protected long EpochSeconds(DateTime dt)
    {
        var ts = dt.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1970 8:00:00 AM"));

        return ((((((ts.Days * 24) + ts.Hours) * 60) + ts.Minutes) * 60) + ts.Seconds);
    }

    protected int Score(int upVotes, int downVotes)
    {
        return upVotes - downVotes;
    }

    public double HotScore(int upVotes, int downVotes, DateTime date)
    {
        var s = Score(upVotes, downVotes);
        var order = Math.Log(Math.Max(Math.Abs(s), 1), 10);
        var sign = Math.Sign(s);
        var seconds = EpochSeconds(date) - 1134028003;
        return Math.Round(order + sign * ((double)seconds / 45000), 7);
    }
}
```

Based on the model output from the link provided, I should see gradual decay at 0-13 hours, and sharp decay after that.

What I'm seeing is very homogeneous decay, and scores much higher than the output from the original code (original code: 3480-3471).

Here is how I'm testing:

```
        Calculation c = new Calculation();
        double now = c.HotScore(100, 2, DateTime.Now);
        double fivehoursago = c.HotScore(100, 2, DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5));
        double tenhoursago = c.HotScore(100, 2, DateTime.Now.AddHours(-10));
        double elevenhoursago = c.HotScore(100, 2, DateTime.Now.AddHours(-11));
        double twelvehoursago = c.HotScore(100, 2, DateTime.Now.AddHours(-12));
        double thirteenhoursago = c.HotScore(100, 2, DateTime.Now.AddHours(-13));
        double fiftyhoursago = c.HotScore(100, 2, DateTime.Now.AddHours(-50));
        double onehundredhoursago = c.HotScore(100, 2, DateTime.Now.AddHours(-100));
        Console.WriteLine(now.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(fivehoursago.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(tenhoursago.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(elevenhoursago.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(twelvehoursago.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(thirteenhoursago.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(fiftyhoursago.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(onehundredhoursago.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Output values:

```
now:               4675.2993816
five hours:        4674.8993816
ten hours:         4674.4993816
eleven hours:      4674.4193816
twelve hours:      4674.3393816
thirteen hours:    4674.2593816
fifty hours:       4671.2993816
one-hundred hours: 4667.2993816
```

Clearly it's SORT of working right, but something is off. It could be related to the lack of true *nix Epoch support, or the lack of analogous microseconds calculation, but something isn't quite right.

Possible reference resources:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/03/20/93332.aspx
http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/07/10/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-.net-datetime.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary problem is that the hot algorithm is time dependent. Your calculating the hot score at `DateTime.Now`, whereas the article was written on 23. Nov 2010 (look at the bottom of the article).

With some trial and error, it seems the data was calculated at approximately 2010-11-23 07:35. Try using that value rather than `DateTime.Now`, and you should get about the same results as the data in the graph shown.

Mind you, you could make the following improvements to your code:

```
public class Calculation
{
    private static readonly DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    private double EpochSeconds(DateTime dt)
    {
        return (dt - Epoch).TotalSeconds;
    }

    private int Score(int upVotes, int downVotes)
    {
        return upVotes - downVotes;
    }

    public double HotScore(int upVotes, int downVotes, DateTime date)
    {
        int s = Score(upVotes, downVotes);
        double order = Math.Log(Math.Max(Math.Abs(s), 1), 10);
        int sign = Math.Sign(s);
        double seconds = EpochSeconds(date) - 1134028003;
        return Math.Round(order + sign * seconds / 45000, 7);
    }
}
```

My results:

```
3479.0956039
3478.6956039
3478.2956039
3478.2156039
3478.1356039
3478.0556039
3475.0956039
3471.0956039
```

Changes:

- Used the declared Epoch rather than a convert of 1970-01-01 08:00:00 (I think 08:00 is a mistake).
- You can subtract two dates using `a - b`; which is the same as `a.Subtract(b)` but more succinct and it mirrors the original Python code.
- A timespan *does* give you microsecond precision (Ticks are the smallest unit and equal 100 nanoseconds).
- Also, TotalSeconds gives you the total number of seconds within a time span; no need to recalculate that. The fractional part even gives you your microsecond precision.
- By returning double from EpochSeconds, you keep this precision.
- Made the data types explicit rather than `var` to clearly indicate what variable is what (they match the method signatures, so no implicit upcasting).
- Changed unneeded `protected` to `private` and made the `Epoch` a constant.

Comment: Just need to get back from work to verify, but let me say thank you for taking so much time on this. I know it's easier to answer the short questions :)